# crashs on android L when load so

Tags: android-ndk, dlopen, loadlibrary, skia

I have a skia shared library generated from skia source code, i want use it to draw something in my  cpp file. This project runs well on android M and N, but it crashed on android L.

This is my CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(libs "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs")
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/android)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/atlastext)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/c)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/codec)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/config)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/core)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/effects)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/encode)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/gpu)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/pathops)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/ports)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/private)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/svg)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/utils)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/views)

#--------------------------------------------------- import ---------------------------------------------------#
add_library(libmyskia SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(libmyskia PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${libs}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libmyskia.so")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 -fexceptions -fno-rtti")

add_library(eskia
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/eskia.cpp )

find_library( android-lib
              android)

target_link_libraries(eskia
        libmyskia
        ${android-lib}
    )
```

I load the library in my activity:

```
 static {
            System.loadLibrary("myskia");
            System.loadLibrary("eskia");
        }
```

Here is the crash info, has anyone meet this?

```
  04-02 16:46:55.319 21449-21449/com.eastedu.skiaandroid E/art: dlopen("/data/app/com.eastedu.skiaandroid-2/lib/arm/libeskia.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE" referenced by "libeskia.so"...
    04-02 16:46:55.319 21449-21449/com.eastedu.skiaandroid D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    04-02 16:46:55.319 21449-21449/com.eastedu.skiaandroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.eastedu.skiaandroid, PID: 21449
        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE" referenced by "libeskia.so"...
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:383)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:997)
            at com.eastedu.skiaandroid.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:17)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1387)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5689)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at enter code herecom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Your linker cannot find `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info`. This is strange: I have it defined even on a 4.2.2 device, in **libgabi++.so**. You can try to load this lib explicitly.

Comment: Thanks , Alex Cohn. This problem solved after add :                 
      arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared'       in gralde.build.